# Manually formatting url starting with http or https in string for UITextView of iOS/Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I would like to select a bunch of urls only starting with http or https from a string. In UITextView, `.dataDetectorTypes` can be set to `.link` for making all urls into blue underlined text.

For example, from `"www.google.com and https://www.gogole.com and http://www.google.com as well as "google.com"` I would like to make only url starting with https or http into blue underlined text and keep them in the same original sentence, if not in a new sentence with modified selected urls. 
Is it possible for such approach? Or which way i could implement that.?

Comment: And who ever downvoted the question, kindly suggest how I can improve my question.

Comment: If I understood correctly. Create the NSMutableAttributedString, use a `NSDataDetector` to detect links on (`myAttributedString.string`) and call `enumerateMatches(in:options:range:using:)` on the `dataDetector`. In the enumeration, add the corresponding attributed to `myAttributedString`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to do so:
Use a `NSMutableAttributedString`.
Use `NSDataDetector` to find all the links.
Enumerate (`enumerateMatches(in:options:range:using:)`) and edit according to your rule if you want to add or not the `NSAttributedStringKey.link`.

```
let initialString = "www.google.com and https://www.gogole.com and http://www.google.com as well as \"google.com\""
let linkDetector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: initialString)

linkDetector.enumerateMatches(in: attributedString.string,
                              options: [],
                              range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.string.utf16.count)) { (match, flags, stop) in
                                if let match = match, match.resultType == NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link, let url = match.url {
                                    if let range = Range(match.range, in: attributedString.string) {
                                        let substring = attributedString.string[range]
                                        if substring.hasPrefix("http") {
                                            attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: url, range: match.range)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
}
```

I used the test `substring.hasPrefix("http")`, but you can use the one you want.

Output:

```
attributedString:
www.google.com and {
}https://www.gogole.com{
    NSLink = "https://www.gogole.com";
} and {
}http://www.google.com{
    NSLink = "http://www.google.com";
} as well as "google.com"{
}
```